# Writing in second language

Tags: structure, language, poetry

I am an Indonesian but mostly write in English.  Most of my poems are written in English.  What terms and rules should I notice? considering that my idea comes to mind in English not  my native language.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking.  Are you asking about rules for poetic forms in English?  Particular English terms/words that have special meanings (symbolism, etc)?  Something else?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Agreed. This needs clarification.

Comment: Des, I'm closing this question so you can clarify, so people don't answer the wrong question (or guess).  Please ping Neil or me when you've [edit]ed.  Thanks!  (And please don't be put off by the canned "not real" language below; we don't get to control that.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I am failed to make you both understand what I mean :) I should have said English for writing in general, and for poetry writing in particular.

Comment: @Neil Fein: As I wrote to Monica :)

Comment: @Des, no need to apologize; we're trying to help you improve the question, not make you feel bad.  Could you clarify what you mean by "what terms and rules should I notice"?  Are you asking about how to choose the best English words for the foreign-language concepts you're trying to convey?

Comment: @MonicaCellio That would be included too, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I'm a South-American-born Chinese and I write novels and [short stories](http://alexandrochen.com/existential-fiction/) in English.

I'm not familiar with poetry rules, but I think that's the easy part. The difficult part is to write like a native speaker (or at least, good enough to be taken seriously by native speakers).

These are some methods I use:

- I read everyday (e.g. two novels a week)
- I write and get corrected by native speakers
- I check my sentences on Google to make sure native speakers are using them
- I watch movies and listen to songs in English

I think this is more a matter of getting used to thinking and expressing yourself in English rather than learning some set of rules. Which should be easy as long as you have passion in what you do.

Comment: Making a poem with western nature needs a very deep intuition.  While you have never been living in west with its four seasons, what do you think if I could make poems of Spring and Winter? :)  Pleased to read your suggestions!

Comment: @Des Well, I'm pretty sure Spring and Winter also occurs in your country. Use the **English language** to write about things that happen around you.

Comment: NO, No! We have only dry season and monsoon here, as I am residing in a tropical country.   "Use the English language to write about things that happen around you" That's what I always try to do.